# Registering dependent modules dynamically in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to have multiple AngularJs modules inside the Areas of a ASP.NET MVC application. Each module would be a separate application. This will help us deploy each module independently without rebuilding the main application. Please suggest if this approach can be followed.

Also I wanted to have the index.html page in the main ASP.NET MVC application (which would have the other SPAs in the Areas section). I wanted to check how to load the different modules without hard coding them all in the main module(please check the app.js part below)

**index.html would have ng-app='app' :**

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<title/>
<body>
<!-- some code -->
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    <how to load the dependent modules dynamically with out hard coding them here>`
]);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If all you want is to pass in a config file you can manually bootstrap the app instead of using `ng-app`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that dynamically creates the dependency array.

```
var getDependents = function () {
    var dependents = [];
    dependents.push("ngRoute");
    dependents.push("somethingElse");
    //dynamically add more
    return dependents;
};

var myApp = angular.module('app', getDependents());
```